# iPhone backup encryption with password cannot be disabled

Tags: ios, backup, iphone, encryption, configuration-profiles

Hi have backups which encrypted with passwords and **i know the backup password**, i can restore it.
There is not any problem.

But i want to disable encrypting backup with password, here is the problem.
In iTunes Encrypt "iPhone backup with password" checkbox is checked and disabled.
So i cannot be able to change it.

Answer (score 3):

My phone had a Profile, which forces backups to be encrypted.

To enable unencrypted iPhone backups again, I removed any Profiles from my phone under Settings -> General -> Profiles.

Profiles can be either Provisioning or Configuration Profiles, and are used for iPhone development and by Enterprise Deployment tools. More information about profiles can be found in the [Apple Enterprise Deployment Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Don't restore it if you don't know the encryption backup password or you won't be able to restore your phone to the state it was at before you went into DFU mode.
Also, restoring your phone actually doesn't uncheck the box - I have tried!

Answer (score -3):

Hold the home button and the power button together' so that it will be DFU mode. and restore it.

Comment: This is really wrong even if the OP wanted to know how to get into DFU. DFU requires several closely times presses and releases as you connect the device to a powered USB cable and/or software modifications to call the state directly. What other steps are needed to address the question at hand?