# Unable to uncheck the "Encrypt Backup" box, in iTunes 11

Tags: itunes, backup

I am running iTunes 11, and have just plugged in my iPad 2 (running iOS 6.1.2) in.

I would like my back-ups to be unencrypted, but I can't uncheck the check box that would allow me to, as you can see in the screenshot:

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

I do know the backup password, and have tried changing it but to no avail.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/81006/9058. Can you check the answer there and report back whether it solved your problem as well?

Comment: Just wanted to write the same..

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and documented the procedure [here](https://wiitez.blogspot.sg/2016/12/how-to-disable-iphone-requiring-backup.html):

> I have found that this can be caused by installed Profiles
>   (Crashlytics Provisioning Profile in my case, but some other people
>   reported the same with an M1 (the telecommunication company) Profile
>   installed).
>
> To delete it:
>
> - Go to Settings > General > Profile, tap on the app’s configuration profile.
> - Then tap Delete Profile. If asked, enter your device pass-code, then tap Delete.
>
> Then:
>
> - Go to the Summary page for your device in iTunes
> - Double check "Automatically Back Up" is set to "This computer"
> - Double check "Encrypt iPhone backup" is *unchecked*
> - Press "Back Up Now"

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score 0):

Odd. Offhand, the first thing I would think of is restoring the device, even though that's a bit of a pain. But that might not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can, if you want delete your backup and create a new one, to do so head over to **iTunes** > **prefrences** > **devices** select your backup then delete it, now plug in your phone and create a new backup, should take an average 4-7 minutes depending on your device and content on your iDevice